# Почему сайт до сих пор в бета-стадии?

Tags: обсуждение, faq

Сайту уже много лет, у него есть достаточно активное сообщество, но нет собственного оформления как у других сайтов SE. Почему? Какие условия нужно выполнить для получения нового дизайна?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно уникальный дизайн для сайта создается после прохождения аттестации.

Насколько мне известно, существует большой ряд критериев для прохождения аттестации. Аттестация означает, что мы ожидаем самостоятельное развитие сайта в будущем. [Одним из главных критериев аттестации, но не единственным, является наличие десяти вопросов в день в среднем.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) На данный момент на сайте задается в среднем 6 вопросов в день.

Важный для развития бета-сайта этап — назначение модераторов. На время до аттестации модераторы назначаются без выборов, по принципу наибольшего участия и интереса к организации самого сообщества. Главным событием аттестации сообщества является возможность проводить выборы модераторов (и, конечно же, независимый дизайн).

Еще один немаловажный фактор успеха сайта – активное общение участников на Мете и в чате: оно крайне положительно влияет на сплоченность участников.

**Подробнее об этом написано в статье ["Развитие сообщества «Русский язык»"](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA?cb=1).**