# Развитие сообщества «Русский язык»

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Сайту «Русский язык» уже много лет, но он до сих пор находится в стадии бета-тестирования. Это накладывает [ряд ограничений](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta), например нам не доступен собственный дизайн, мы не можем инициировать выборы модераторов и др. Чтобы избавиться от них, нужно пройти аттестацию, [набрать](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) критическую массу.
Поскольку, как уже было сказано, сайт существует довольно долго и у него есть определенные достижения, список того, что необходимо для выхода из беты, значительно короче:

- нужно достигнуть показателя в **десять вопросов в день** (как минимум); сейчас задается приблизительно 7 вопросов ежедневно;
- нужно активное **участие сообщества на Мете** (то есть здесь); Мета — полезная часть сайта: на ней можно высказать свои пожелания о работе сайта, сообщить об ошибке, внести предложение, обсудить какие-то другие вещи, связанные с сайтом.

Думаю, что всем будет приятно видеть не стандартное серое оформление, а особенное, специально разработанное с учетом мнения сообщества. Список того, что требуется, совсем мал, нужно только ваше участие! Многие заходят на сайт ежедневно — так задайте вопрос, это нетрудно, а еще легче — зайти на Мету и проверить, нет ли вопросов, требующих вашего внимания. Вы заметили какую-то опечатку в Справке, вам что-то не нравится в устройстве сайта, у вас появилась отличная идея? Создайте вопрос на [Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/)! Не стоит забывать и о [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rus.stackexchange.com): в нем можно обсуждать практически все — начиная иллокутивной силой предложения и заканчивая тем, что вам подарили на Новый год.

Всего лишь немного усилий — и долгожданная цель будет достигнута! Именно от вашего участия зависит будущее сайта!

---

**Если у вас есть мысли о том, чего сейчас не хватает сайту и какие цели стоит поставить, опишите их в своем ответе.**

Answer (score 5):

Поскольку этот вопрос стал уже назойливо светиться в важных, позволю себе уточнить.

> Всего лишь три "нужно" — и долгожданная цель будет достигнута!

I Какая цель? Красивые рисуночки вокруг ответов? По мне они нужны не больше, чем веселые картинки в трактате Канта.

II Кто именно и как долго эту цель ждал? Не, я не против, если оно будет, но рвать жилы ради какого-то там признака, что сайт-де не бета, а гамма... Нет, увольте.

III Самое главное, если те, кому эта цель важна (судя по всему это Aer и Galina) надо сами не видят путей достижения цели, а просят о том безразличных ко всему пользователей, то о чем вообще речь?

---

Мое виденье ситуации.

1. Я могу и сорок в день задать. Возьму учебник за пятый класс - и все упражнения из него будут здесь. Только Кому это надо? Николай недвусмысленно сказал, что приоритета количества над качеством быть не должно. Это значит, что гонка за десятью вопросами превратится в общеукрепляющий бег на месте "не догоню, так согреюсь".

   Если честно, мне даже хорошие интересные вопросы надоело задавать, зная, что из всех отвечающих Только Галина и Серж их прочтут - и отминусят по в порядке обмена любезностями. И даже не известно, прочтут ли.

   Так что тут надо что-то "в консерватории поправить", а не бросаться лозунгами.
2. Если Николаю это надо, пусть назначает модератора, а не создает картинку активности масс.
3. А это еще мне зачем? Я пару раз поделился своими соображениями - воз и ныне там. Больше не буду без особой нужды. Если бы я видел что по этим обсуждения принимались какие-то реальные меры... А пока - в лучшем случае косметический ремонт в виде уточнений Факов и Инсрукций.

---

Вот, например, кто-нить пытался разобраться, что такое метки - и зачем они нужны? Реально метки не работают вообще. Кто что хочет, тот то и пишет.

А реально метки могли бы принести какую-то пользу, если бы за основу была взята какая-то единая система с тезаурусом. Метка показывает, к какому разделу языкознания вообще относится вопрос. Ну полсотни таких меток при нашем количестве вопросов более чем достаточно.

Aer, насколько знаю, пытался навести там порядок сабельной атакой. Бросил. И что дальше? Я перестал на метки обращать внимание уже давно.

Comment: Совершенно с вами не согласен. Идеология Stack Exchange заключается в том, что сообщество создается самими участниками. Компания, со своей стороны, заботится о развитии за счет: 1) предоставления экспертизы (сейчас в системе более 150 сайтов, на основе этих данных можно предполагать, каких направлений должно придерживаться сообщество); 2) добавление игровых механик на сайт (это необходимо, чтобы сайтом было приятно пользоваться).

Comment: Мне не до конца понятна подобная позиция. Вы пришли, сказали, что все плохо и вы палец о палец не ударите, чтобы сделать лучше, и, более того, кому бы то ни было ничего делать не советуете. Подскажите, зачем?

Comment: @ NicolasChabanovsky  По пунктам. *1. Вы пришли, сказали, что все плохо* - я этого не говорил. 2. *и вы палец о палец не ударите, чтобы сделать лучше,* - и  не буду, пока не пойму, зачем это, и вы не сформулируете конкретную задачу . 3. *ничего делать не советуете* - ничего из того, что предложено. А в целом я ответил, меня нынешняя ситуация более или менее устраивает.

Comment: По вашим действиям на сайте, прекрасно видно, что вам интересно развитие сообщества. Всвязи с чем, подобная позиция становится еще более непонятной.

Comment: *Идеология Stack Exchange заключается в том* - да знаю я, в чем она заключается. Только мне до идеологии дела нет. Давно вышел из комсомольского возраста. Если мне что-то интересно, то я без всякой идеологии это делаю. А если нет - идеология не поможет.

Comment: @LazyBadger с вашего позволения, Ваш покорный слуга - программист с почти полувековым  стажем. Идеология тэгов тут не нужна, хотя это и абсолютно прозрачная вещь. Речь идет об идеологии сообщества и всей системы SE.

Comment: А по мне позиция весьма понятная и логичная. На сайте большинство вопросов -- это школьники, которым лень домашку самим делать. Вау, новый дизайн. Вау, можно выбирать модераторов. Ну, можно развить кипучую деятельность, а остальных обозвать старыми критиканами.

Comment: `Метка показывает, к какому разделу языкознания вообще относится вопрос` – да, в этом и есть смысл меток.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, хорошо, выйдет сайт из беты. И что от этого поменяется кардинально?

Отсутствие дизайна — это какая-то мелочь, никак не мешающая задавать вопросы и отвечать на вопросы.

Выборы модератора это тоже какая-то промежуточная цель. Ну выбрали модераторов (их проще назначить), хорошо, и что дальше? Для чего это всё, что с этим делать дальше?

На текущий момент общество бывшей "одной пятой суши" нисколько не заинтересовано в русском языке: оно больше озабочено вопросами выживания и увеличения своего благосостояния.

Самый отличный показатель этого: то, что сайт используется преимущественно школьниками, которые спрашивают, как решить домашку или их мамашами, которые готовы инвестировать в образование детей, чтобы они потом больше заработали.

Уберите все эти вопросы школьников — ну сколько у вас останется человек в сообществе? Насчитаете хотя бы десяток?

А больше останется вопросов, чем в [сообществе по изучению языка наиболее вероятного противника](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)?

Я как-то с Николаем беседовал на тему того, что русский язык не сложился как язык международного обмена. Учи английский, если хочешь знать программирование. Учи английский, если тебе нужны новейшие книги по экономике, математике, политологии, ... <любая другая область, подставить по вкусу>. Единственное, ради чего стоит изучать русский язык — это ради того, чтобы прочитать в оригинале ветхие книги, написанные русскими поэтами и и писателями столетия назад.

Ну Николай ладно — он профессионально занимается этим самым развитием сообществ, должностные обязанности, все дела. Поэтому поставить цель "сделать дизайн" и идти к ней — это для него уже хорошо, ибо 'dvizhuha' и трафик.

Поэтому цели вы ставите все какие-то мелкие: самоцели — цели ради цели. Думаете, оно того стоит? Попробуйте придумать что-то более значимое.

Я таких целей, увы, не вижу, @behemothus тоже не видит.

Однако, не спешите упрекать в критиканстве: предложите что-то стоящее — уверен, что найдутся и желающие помочь.

Comment: Нужны более крупные цели, но какие? Увеличение количества вопросов и популярности сайта в целом? Не уверен, что на данном этапе развития это получится сделать без спама. Конкретные предложения по улучшению того, что есть (например, меток), будут опубликованы позже. Сообщество без модераторов — ужасная вещь, надо сказать. Вы не знаете, но немало участников покинуло сайт именно по этой причине. Надо продолжать? Про мамаш и школьников вы не в тему, почитайте вопросы типа "где запятая" и удостоверьтесь, что далеко не все они "школьные". Даже если убрать их, активных участников меньше не станет.

Comment: Что за наиболее вероятные противники? У нас таких нет. Вы бы лучше не порицали, а взяли и предложили что-то стоящее.

Comment: Если бы я знал хорошие цели - я бы давно предложил, об этом совершенно прозрачно написано. У вас тоже ничего нет: кроме минуса вам ничем не нашлось ответить по существу. Хотите организовать еще одну колонну ушедших с сайта, чтобы не мешали делать мелкие, но задачи - так скажите словами. А вообще - удачи вам в новом году, творческих задач и побед. Ну а если [заглянете помочь](http://opencorpora.org/) - тем более буду рад видеть.

Comment: Ну, честно говоря, не совсем прозрачно... но да ладно. Почему же ничего по существу — я вроде бы ответил конкретно. На мой взгляд (*простого* участника), вы чутка переборщили с противником и мамочками. // Спасибо, что врагом народа объявили, а то уже несколько дней с назначения прошло, а я все жду, жду... дождался)) А если серьезно, спасибо за отклик и мнение, это очень полезно, буду рад услышать его и по другим вопросам в дальнейшем. Всяческих успехов в наступающем году и вам! *(Благодарю за поздравление приглашение.)*

Comment: Да Господи, наиболее вероятный противник это западный мир,а не конкурирующие сообщества на so! Не надо в меня проецировать свои страхи, вы в моих словах уж невесть что видите. Если вам самому хочется увидеть что-то - вы и увидите, и дождетесь... Но будет ли это иметь отношение к реальности или это только ваши собственные страхи?

Comment: Ах, так вы про Америку! Ну это уже бредни какие-то, простите.

Comment: Вы знаете, у меня кажется появились мысли насчёт "Не уверен, что на данном этапе развития это получится сделать без спама", [пойдёмте в этот топик](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8-russe), обсудим один из возможных примеров.

Comment: `Ну, хорошо, выйдет сайт из беты. И что от этого поменяется кардинально` — а бета-сообщества не удаляются по истечении определённого времени как бесперспекивные?

Answer (score 3):

Уважаемые старожилы сообщества! Я с огромным интересом (абсолютно не преувеличиваю!) читаю ВСЕ новые и, когда успеваю, часть старых вопросов и ответов. Иногда сама пытаюсь ответить, не всегда исчерпывающе и полно, но, к сожалению, ограничена во времени. Получаю огромное удовольствие от ответов и переписки части "профессионалов" и любителей русского языка. Хотя не совсем соглашаюсь, но это действительно очень интересно и познавательно. Это очень здорово. У сайта есть достижения.

Два месяца на сайте не дают мне права судить, но! Я согласна с Lazy Badger, что нужен человек-технарь, хорошо разбирающийся в сайтостроении, умеющий и "могущий" навести порядок в среде филологов.  Я за порядок ВЕЗДЕ. Это облегчает жизнь. Ещё раз подчёркиваю, я дилетант, и мне очень сложно (или просто лень, потому что требует много времени, а я хочу, чтобы технически всё было проще):

1. отформатировать текст в ответе;
2. разобраться, как реально "работают" эти метки.

Я понимаю, что они относят вопрос к определённому разделу языкознания. Но как они систематизированы, связаны между собой. Не вижу логики ... и ещё несколько НЕ...

Я тоже хочу, чтобы Русский язык вышел из статуса БЭТЫ, перешёл на более высокий уровень. Если надо сделать что-то конкретное для процветания полюбившегося мне сайта, всегда с удовольствием... Но пока я много работаю и , к сожалению, времени нет... (как, наверное, у большинства).

Если разберусь, попробую принять участие в обсуждениях и на Мете, и в чате. Буду рада новому оформлению. Но, честно говоря, меня и старое вполне устраивает.  Я всё равно буду посещать сайт, он уже (без преувеличения) вошёл в мою жизнь. Кому как, а мне интересно.

Поэтому, когда во всём разберусь, попробую дать советы. Пока не рискую.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Приятно, что есть неравнодушные люди! :)

Comment: Уверен, для понимания сайта не нужны какие–либо знания в том, как разрабатывать сайты. Необходимо лишь желание структурировать знания.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky всё-таки инструкции для гуманитариев нужно писать гораздо подробнее и точнее, чем для технарей. Те же метки и форматирование очень привычны для нас, а здесь вызывают вопросы. А вот про пунктуацию и типографику наоборот, у нас подробные инструкции понадобились.

Comment: Метки действительно относят вопрос к определённому разделу или теме. Но они складываются стихийно, как сам язык, они подвержены объединениям, заменам, устареванию. Вы тоже можете привнести свою долю порядка в систему меток.

Answer (score 2):

Как мне кажется, главное – начать!

Все начинается с инфраструктуры – инструментов сообщества. К ним можно отнести:

- основополагающие правила сообщества (например, https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- справочный центр (главная страница справки и все разделы);
- механизмы модерации (закрытие вопросов, очереди проверок т. д.);
- система меткок;
- приведение существующей базы знаний в порядок.

Можно поставить [долгосрочные цели](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/955/), а каждый месяц отслеживать их. При этом, непрерывно делать небольшие улучшения (например, раз в неделю улучшать одну страницу справочного центра).

Именно так происходило развитие сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.