# Хотели бы вы быть модератором сообщества?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено

Модераторы – неотъемлемая часть успешного сайта, без которой невозможно вообразить дружное сообщество коллег. Сейчас сайту Русский язык как никогда нужны активные участники, готовые стать лидерами и [помочь сообществу выйти из беты](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/). Спешу предложить выбрать *первых модераторов сообщества*. Выбор будет происходить из числа тех, кто опубликует свою заявку в ответ на этот вопрос.

Вы можете ознакомиться с тем, [кто такие модераторы и какова их роль](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) в [справочном центре](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help).

#### Что необходимо, чтобы претендовать на позицию модератора?

Предполагается, что будущие модераторы знакомы с системой и сообществом, что будет отражено в их репутации: для отклика, у вас должна быть 1000 баллов репутации и более.

Пожалуйста, в вашем отклике расскажите чуть-чуть про себя, а также укажите, почему вы хотите стать модератором сообщества и почему сообщество должно выбрать именно вас (то есть почему вы будете хорошим модератором).

Быть модератором – не означает быть самым главным знатоком русского языка. Быть модератором – означает, проявлять интерес, доброту и заботу о сообществе и его организации (конечно же, при этом вы можете быть знатоком!)

Русский язык – далеко не новое сообщество, сравнимое по популярности со [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Уверен, вместе мы сможем попробовать приблизиться к сообществу по программированию не только по интересу к созданной базе знаний, но и по количеству вопросов задаваемых в день – одной из главных метрик активности на сайте.

С нетерпением ждем ваших откликов!

---

Спасибо всем, кто подал заявку и тем, кто участвовал в голосовании! Спешу поздравить двух новых модераторов:

- [Марк Из](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1067/);
- [Aer](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/178412/).

Уверен, присутствие модераторов положительно повлияет на сообщество!

Comment: А что необходимо указать в заявке? (Помимо самого желания.)

Comment: @Aer Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, в ближайшее время обновлю заявку.

Comment: @Aer Здорово! С нетерпением жду!

Comment: Не совсем ясно, идёт ли речь о выборах (с голосованием участников сайта) или о назначении временных модераторов из числа желающих.

Comment: @zaq Любой участник сообщества вправе высказаться за/против (в виде комментария или голосования). Если кандидатов будет больше чем вакантных мест, то модераторами станут те, кто набрал больше голосов. Как мне кажется, на данном этапе будет здорово выбрать двух или трех модераторов.

Comment: А вот это мне нравится куда больше. Я ведь когда-то предлагал устроить некое подобие голосования, кандидатов с предвыборными программами. Куда лучше чем отжимать ту же программу от инертной массы...

Comment: Я подготовил для кандидатов небольшую анкету.
http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/145 Надеюсь, что кандидаты воспользуются случаем, чтобы показать свою реальную заинтересованность в представлении себя сообществу. Aer, от вас хотел бы ответов в первую очередь.

Comment: @behemothus Это не выборы, по большому счету. Полноценные выборы со всей процедурой (как она описана [Мете Stack Overflow на русском](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2044/)) возможны лишь в случае выхода из беты. Это больше вопрос для энтузиастов. Вопросы/опросы, как мне кажется,  в данном случае не имеют значения. Основное требование – понимание системы и интерес к сообществу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну определитесь тогда, что это выборы, или не выборы. Я не про процедуру (прекрасно понимаю, что выбор в нашем случае все равно останется за вами), а про программу кандидатов, т. е . суть  мероприятия, которое я якобы "саботирую". Если значение имеет только интерес, то кто может его оценить, кроме вас? Вот понимание системы - это да. Но его тоже никто не оценит, кроме вас. А мне лично хотелось бы видеть в модераторе (если он так  уж необходим) человека с понятной мне позицией, конкретного и неангажированного.

Comment: Прежде всего то, чем и как он будет двигать сообщество к им же намеченным целям. Если такой вопрос неуместен, то прошу извинить.

Comment: @behemothus Для проведения полноценных выборов сообщество еще не набрало необходимый масштаб («выборы» предполагают выбор, как минимум!). Модераторы, как вы верно заметили, назначаются, в нашем случае, а не выбираются. При этом, модераторами должны стать энтузиасты по личному желанию и с согласия сообщества. Поэтому, я полагаю, анкета, как таковая, не нужна. Достаточно истории участия в жизни сообщества и краткого резюме о себе, чтобы сообщество знало человека чуть более «лично».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Николай, я не настаиваю. Делайте как хотите.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю свою кандидатуру. На сайте я зарегистрировался в июле 2012 г., ещё до того как он переехал на новую платформу. За это время набрал более 19000 очков рейтинга и умудрился всерьёз не поссориться ни с одним  из действующих участников сообщества. Не являюсь филологом по образованию, и местами моя грамотность оставляет желать лучшего, поэтому, кроме явных опечаток, орфографию и пунктуацию чужих сообщений не трогаю, хотя неправильную вёрстку сообщения по возможности исправляю.

Так как за последнее время тематика вопросов ушла именно в ту плоскость, где мои познания слабы, отвечаю редко, но просматриваю вопросы почти каждый день и периодически помечаю вопросы на закрытие, удаление или отмечаю тревогой (на данный момент 30 полезных тревог).

В целом, думаю, что был бы полезен сообществу в качестве модератора.

Comment: Я поддержу, если это требуется. Все-таки четыре года "знакомы". И мне нравится ваш конкретный и содержательный подход к проблемам. Вы остепенились? А то мне, помнится, из-за диссертации у вас почти не было времени.

Comment: @behemothus Привык к графику, сменил работу и женился, поэтому время на различные игры пришлось сократить, а  ресурсы подобные этому только поднимают мой авторитет в глазах жены.

Comment: Ох, сколько всего-то! Ну поздравляю. Тогда про диссертацию не спрашиваю ))).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что могу оставить заявку.

Я обратил внимание на сайт более чем год назад, и меня сразу заинтересовал его формат — вопрос-ответ, ничего лишнего. Ознакомившись с основным содержанием, я решил, что сообщество уже сформировалось, и присоединиться к нему будет трудно. Однако по прошествии нескольких месяцев я все-таки завел учетную запись и стал отвечать на вопросы, а также их задавать. С тех пор интерес не угасает, и я захожу на сайт по нескольку раз на дню в поисках нерешенной проблемы, нередко сам задаю вопросы.

По своей натуре я люблю развитие, прогресс, поэтому, собственно, наблюдая своеобразный [застой](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA), я постарался привлечь внимание сообщества. Если говорить о модерации (вообще говоря, у меня есть опыт комьюнити-менеджмента), я всегда следую правилам сообщества, при этом понимая, что есть проблемы, требующие специального подхода.

Конкретизируя:

- Мы выяснили, что есть перечень необходимого для выхода сайта из стадии беты. Нужно его реализовать.
- Есть другие проблемы, требующие решения: например, система меток, корректировка Справки и др.

Хочется добавить, что сообщество Stack Overflow на русском — хороший пример, к истории развития которого, безусловно, стоит присмотреться.

Comment: Aer, не могли бы вы как-то развернуть "предвыборную программу". Пока она состоит в общем-то из трех частей. 1. Декларативная (имеет место застой) 2. реверанса (какой хороший сайт, но есть проблемы)  3. лозунга (выйдем из стадии беты). Ну первая часть - ладно, ваше мнение хотя я лично никакого застоя на наблюдаю. Со второй - уже непонятно. Конкретно, что за проблемы с метками, справкой - и самое главное! - как вы их решать думаете (жопустим, что это задача именно модератора). По поводу беты - а зачем из неё выходить? Дизайн меня не волнует абсолютно.

Comment: До некоторой степени понимаю, что  это престиж и т. п.  Но если только это, то задача неблагодарная.

Comment: @behemothus Пожалуйста, не саботируйте событие!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky О каком саботаже может идти речь? Я даже анкетку набросал для желающих. Если же это предложение мне принять участие в выборах, так скажите прямо, я подумаю.

Comment: @behemothus я ответил на вопросы анкеты. Метки: их очень много, нет систематичности, нет синонимов и описаний. Пользователям довольно трудно понять, когда какие метки стоит использовать. В справке есть немало опечаток, некоторые пункты правил расплывчаты, а некоторых, возможно, недостает. Например, нужно точно описать, что мы считаем д / з и как мы поступаем с ним. Как решать? Большинство вопросов стоит выносить на обсуждение — для этого есть Мета. Например, те же метки: нужно совместно выработать четкую систему, по которой создаются описания, какие метки полезны, а какие — нет и т. д.

Comment: Да я видел, уже и прокомментировал. Спасибо.

Comment: Насчет меток. Вы опять неконкретны. Я предлагал вариант: взять за основу основные понятия академического курса - и ими ограничиться. Обсуждать такие вещи - это полная несуразица. С кем? Да тут три с половиной  человека понимает, как метка работает (по задумке). Аналогичный вопрос - по заголовкам. Сто раз уже говорили, что не надо писать бессодержательные заголовки (это в правилах есть) - и что? Опять-таки не понимают, что текст и заголовок - разные поля формы, они по разному обрабатываются... Никому дела нет.

Comment: @behemothus вот, к примеру, другой сайт: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags. Для большинства меток есть понятные описания, которые обладают одинаковой структурой и одинаково понятны. Согласитесь, что если простой человек увидит в описании деепричастий "нефинитная форма глагола, возглавляющая зависимую клаузу...", он впадет в ступор, причем для причастия описанием будет "форма глагола, обладающая признаками прилагательного".

Comment: @Aer вы где-то в параллельной материи плаваете. При чем тут описание? Его мало кто читает даже на программистских ресурсах. Описания больше нужны модератору. Неужели вы серьезно думаете, что человек, пришедший с насущным вопросом, тем более - новичок, будет тратить время, разглядывая описание меток? Ему надо дать выбор из ограниченного числа более или менее знакомых понятий. Грамматика, синтаксис, стилистика, этимология, орфография и т. п.  и т. л. Все остальное тут лишнее. Ведет только к разрастанию меток с одним-двумя вопросами ими помеченными.

Comment: Имха, конечно, но я от вас и хочу такой же имхи - как вы видите эту систему меток, а не как писать описание, это дело десятое, будет такая задача - напишем (под обозримый список, конечно, а не то, как сейчас ).

Comment: @behemothus не уверен, что я где-то плаваю. Воспользуйтесь другой логикой: есть функционал, который, по вашему мнению, нужен, в общем-то, модераторам (я сразу не согласен, имею ли право, или — плаваю?), значит, нужно его убрать из общего доступа, ведь засорение — дело плохое. Другой вариант: есть функционал, который не используется, потому что большинство не подозревает о его существовании; есть опыт использования его другими ресурсами; нужно попытаться исправить положение.

Comment: Вы, по-моему, здравые мысли пишет про ограниченное число "хороших" меток и т. д. Я того же мнения. Описание так-то дело второе. Главное — систематизировать (дать ограниченное число возможных меток, при этом они должны быть конкретные и полезные; "супер-пупер вопрос" или "оборот" — яркий пример расплывчатости и бесполезности).

Comment: @behemothus мне показалось, что вы про описания говорили, я про них и отвечал. А вы про устройство системы... вроде исправился. Кстати, если есть желание, предлагаю [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50794/discussion-between-aer-and-behemothus).

Comment: Я обо всем говорил. В чат - в другой раз, простите, сегодня уже не могу.

Comment: @behemothus ну, если что, готов к диалогу

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо