# Анкета для кандидатов в модераторы

Tags: обсуждение

Предлагаю всем желающим поучаствовать в гонке за [модераторское кресло](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), ответить на несколько простых вопросов.

Представьте, что вы стали модератором сообщества РЯ. Ваши действия в следующих ситуациях.

**1. Вы поправили чей-то вопрос в соответствии со своим пониманием правил сообщества. После этого автор "откатил" назад. Что делаете:**

1a) Верну свой вариант.
1б) Верну свой вариант, дополнив его указанием, что после модератора посты править не принято.
1в) Верну свой вариант, дополнив его указанием причины правки.
1г) Соглашусь с авторским вариантом.
1д) Нажалуюсь админу.
1е) Выпишу предупреждение.
1ж) Закрою вопрос.
1з) Свой вариант (объясните).

**2. Вы получили сигнал о нарушениях этикета сразу от двух участников дискуссии - жалуются друг на друга, нарушения есть, но незначительные**

2a) Выпишу предупреждения обоим, дабы охладить пыл.
2б) Найду зачинщика - и накажу только его, к жертве отнесусь более снисходительно.
2в) Отправлю дискуссию в чат.
2д) Удалю всё без объяснений и действий
2е) Свой вариант (объясните)

**3. Участник раз за разом задает однотипные вопросы, не представляющие особого интереса для сообщества в целом**

3a) буду удалять вопросы! Ресурс - не бесплатный сервис помощи недостаточно квалифицированным работникам.
3б) порадуюсь за увеличение количество вопросов, это же поможет нам выйти на заветные 10 вопросов в день.
3в) отнесусь нейтрально, пусть отвечают, если кому-то не лень.

**4. Участник ничем особо себя не проявивший постоянно занимается правкой чужих вопросов/ответов, занимаясь чисто оформительской работой (т.е. форматированием). Это вызывает видимое раздражение у авторов**

4a) Пусть делает то, что у него получается! Это же хорошо, что у нас всё по общему дизайну.
4б) Объясню любителю правок, что не стоит переусердствовать.
4в) Попрошу автора принять к сведению, что так лучше.
4г) Это не моё дело.

**5. Ни с того ни сего заминусили ваш вопрос/ответ. Вы как модератор можете видеть, кто это сделал.**

5a) Даже и смотреть не буду. Минус без комментария - фига в кармане, а в такой ситуации я - простой участник.
5б) Посмотрю, но выводов делать не буду.
5в) Проведу разъяснительную работу.
5д) Свой вариант.

**6. Вы разошлись в оценке ситуации со своим коллегой, надо принимать какое-то решение.**

6a) Решение принимает тот из вас, кто первым оказался на месте месте.
6б) Решение принимает тот, кто более авторитетен.
6в) Постараюсь найти общий язык - и найти правильное решение.
6д) Свой вариант.

**7. Что важнее для развития сообщества, количество вопросов или качество ответов?**

7a) И то, и другое.
7б) Количество, мы же хотим выйти из бета-стадии!
7в) Качество, без этого толку всё равно не будет.
7г) Не буду об этом думать, пусть админ решает.

**8. Модератор всегда прав?**

8а) Да (если спорит не с админом).
8б) Нет, всегда право только сообщество.
8в) Свой вариант.

**9. Вы уверены, что будете следовать духу своих ответов в реальной работе?**

9a) Да.
9б) Нет.
9в) Нет, но буду стараться.

**10. Вы хотите ответить еще на несколько подобных вопросов?**

10а) Нет, это совершенно бесполезное занятие, стану модератором - разберемся на месте.
10б) Отвечу, но без особого удовольствия.
10в) Да, это поможет мне стать модератором.
10г) Да, это поможет людям составить мнение обо мне.

Answer (score 2):

**1з.** Попытаюсь разобраться в причинах отката и приму решение. Если они обоснованы и не противоречат правилам сообщества и нормам русского языка (автор может считать, что надо писать жи-ши, через ы, но если подобное написание не вытекает из вопроса, то его лучше откатить), оставлю авторский вариант.

**2е** Выдам предупреждение и отправлю в чат.

**3а** Хотя зависит от периодичности. Если не засоряют главную страницу, то и пусть задаёт раз в неделю, а если всё завалено "Можно ли убрать мягкий знак из русского языка в данном конкретном случае?", то буду удалять.

**4бв** Оформителю объясню, что если не уверен, не правь, а автору, если необходимо, азы работы в здешнем редакторе.

**5б** Я любопытный, но не злопамятный.

**6в** У нас общее дело, а значит договориться можно.

**7а** Какая предвыборная компания без популизма.

**8в** Модератор может ошибаться, но если обсуждение сообществом затягивается, то кому-то надо брать на себя ответственность. Ошибочное решение, лучше, чем его отсутствие.

**9в** Не люблю категорических ответов, но этим нормам я старался соответствовать с момента моего появления в сообществе в 2012 г.

**10б** Боюсь, что мои ответы, мало кому интересны, да и могут возникнуть проблемы, если решение по конкретной ситуации будет не соответствовать задекларированным мною принципам, а я не могу исключать подобного.

Comment: Вы хотите стать модератором? Это было бы просто чудесно. Ответы пока не комментирую.

Answer (score 1):

1. Меня настораживает сама формулировка — "в соответствии со своим пониманием". Тем не менее положим, что это какой-то особый случай, который недостаточно хорошо описан в правилах. Во-первых, я могу посоветоваться с командой сайта или, возможно, с опытными участниками сообщества. Во-вторых, редактируя это спорное сообщение, я укажу, в чем, собственно, проблема, то есть чистой отсебятины быть не должно. Если же автор будет против (при этом он не должен нарушать правила), я соглашусь (опять-таки все зависит от ситуации). Дедовщины быть не может: модераторы — обычные пользователи, их мнение по вопросам, связанным с русским языком, имеет ту же силу, что и у остальных.
2. Опять нужна конкретика, однако мне нравится вариант *в*: в чате пользователи могут обсудить разногласия, при этом не засоряя лишней информацией общедоступную страницу. Если нарушения незначительны, я просто попрошу участников дискуссии держать уважительный тон.
3. Это важная проблема, которую я хочу обсудить с другими пользователями. В зависимости от политики сайта могут быть приняты разные решение: например, если в правилах написано, что задавать однотипные вопросы нежелательно, я напомню об этом автору вопросов. Что же касается удаления или закрытия — у нас есть замечательный механизм, позволяющий самим участникам принимать подобные решения.
4. Близок к правде вариант *б*. В [Справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) есть статья, где неплохо описаны условия, при которых желательно вносить исправления. В частности, там говорится: "Незначительные правки не приветствуются".
5. Не знал, честно говоря, что есть такая возможность... Вариант *в* меня рассмешил, но, очевидно, *б* будет лучшим решением (да и зачем смотреть-то?). Ну и, конечно, минус часто является сигналом, что с ответом что-то не так. Я обращу на это внимание.
6. *В*.
7. Вопросы — в идеале — должны быть качественными, но, очевидно, реальность нередко отличается. Это больная тема, как мы уже сумели выяснить; думаю, что такое решение должно приниматься с оглядкой на ситуацию и не единолично.
8. Людям свойственно ошибаться. *Всегда прав* неверно.
9. Как будто присягу даю... Я вроде бы ничего ужасного тут не понаписал, так что скорее уверен)
10. Если это кому-то интересно, то да.

Comment: Мне нравится (в основном), как вы ответили на первую половину вопросов. И не очень - на вторую.  "ролевые элементы" - вот это просто убило.

Comment: @behemothus упс, я думал, что удалил это при редактировании. Прошу прощения.

Comment: По ответу 3 у меня к вам уточняющий вопрос: как вы будете реагировать на "тревоги" у этих вопросов? Формально ни один из них правил не нарушает, но в совокупности это именно однотипные вопросы, на которые нет смысла давать ответ, потому что задающий их не утруждает себя осмысливанием.

Comment: @Mae есть довольно наглядный пример — вопросы пользователя aleksandr12345. Они однотипны: всегда просится объяснить текст простыми словами — тем не менее даже опытные участники (behemothus, Sibylla, Людмила и др.) давали на них ответы, и при этом вопросы остаются открытыми. Так, если вопросы однотипны, но понятны участникам (и они готовы на них ответить), я не буду этому препятствовать. Однако, если задаются вопросы низкого качества, не понятно, что имел в виду автор, их нужно закрывать.

Comment: Да, возьмём для примера эти вопросы. Их, кажется, не помечали тревогой. Допустим, каждый из них отметили тревогой по два произвольных участника как вопрос не по тематике сайта, но в остальном ситуация та же: вопросы с неотрицательным рейтингом, отвеченные, некоторые ответы даже приняты. Вы примете тревоги как точку зрения сообщества, что вопросы надо закрыть, или ответы как сигнал что эта серия вопросов допустима?

Comment: @Mae Вопросы Александра типа http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/428900/178412 я бы оставил открытыми, потому что понятна их причина — он иностранец, пытающийся разобраться в хитросплетениях русской грамматики. Хотя, например, вопрос http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/428887/178412 я бы закрыл из-за обилия текста. Не понятно, чем ответ на него будет полезен другим людям. А так — очень трудно без конкретных примеров говорить о потенциальных действиях.