# С наступающим Новым годом!

Tags: обсуждение

#### Спешу поздравить участников сообщества «Русский язык» с наступающим Новым годом!

Уверен, в этом году мы выйдем на траекторию стабильного развития. С настоящего момента на сайте [появились модераторы](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), у сообщества есть [цели](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/), а это означает, что в новом году нас ждет много положительных перемен!

Answer (score 4):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1SwL.jpg]

Поздравляю всех лингвистов, энтузиастов и любителей Великого и Могучего с Новым Годом!!!

Answer (score 3):

"Русский" ответ: "И Вас туда же!" )))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моё пожелание сайту и модераторам:

да не бойтесь вы живого разговорного языка, 
не разводите пуританского политесу!

Даёшь общение просторечиями, диалектизмами и междометиями!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А желательно - ваще жестикуляцией!

Доходчиво ж!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А Рич объяснит популярно, от чего всем нам будет щасте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всех коллег - с праздником!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]