# Насколько тематичны вопросы про вёрстку текста и текстовый дизайн?

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос возник из обсуждения в комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/429747/182097): один из участников высказал мнение, что вопрос является оффтопиком и не подходит под тематику сообщества.

Хотелось бы уточнить как сообщество оценивает, насколько подобные темы подходят под [тематику сообщества](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Насколько я знаю, сайт находится в статусе "беты" и я не уверен, что есть некая "финальная", принятая версия правил сообщества, от которых можно было бы оттолкнуться в своих рассуждениях.

Также поскольку я [заинтересован](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/182097) в том, чтобы сообщество двигалось вперёд и к каким-то действительно интересным целям я хотел бы высказать в частном порядке своё личное видение, возможно кто-то его поддержит.

В наше время информационные системы получают широкое распространение и эта область очень бурно развивается, в связи с чем постоянно появляются новые вопросы, тесно связанные с вопросами русского языка -- и часть этих вопросов вполне органично "вписывается" в тематику сообщества.

На текущий момент в самом сообществе практически нет таких вопросов, хотя постоянно на мете русского Stack Overflow задаются вопросы или обсуждаются в комментариях, приведу примеры:

- [Кавычки для метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4547/213987) - вопрос на тему расстановки знаков препинания
- [Использование кавычек во фразах про голоса "за" и "против"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4062/213987) - вопрос на тему расстановки знаков препинания для названий элементов интерфейса (кнопок)
- [Правка утверждена/отклонена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4626/213987) - вопрос на тему составления кратких, чётких формулировок; избавление от "канцелярита"; точность перевода
- [Нужно ли как-то выделять «Stack Overflow на русском» в тексте?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4489/213987) - вопрос о правильном написании организаций, не раз задавался на сайте, уже пора в FAQ вносить
- [требуется ли точка в конце всплывающей подсказки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/429747/182097) - вопрос о знаках пунктуации в элементах интерфейса
- [Краткое описание метки и точка в конце предложения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4640/213987) - вопрос о знаках пунктуации в элементах интерфейса
- [Каждому участнику правок по "участнику"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4412/213987) - вопрос о том, как правильно оформлять списки в элементах интефейса

В случае, если подобные вопросы будут считаться одной из дополнительных тематик сообщества -- я думаю, что ru-so из своей практики может поставить достаточно много интересных и полезных вопросов для затравки, а там возможно и из других мест подтянуться "на огонёк" спрашивающие и отвечающие. Кроме того [интерес был и в обратную сторону](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4346/213987): интерфейс и перевод у нас действительно общий и есть много точек соприкосновения, чтобы попробовать поискать взаимовыгодные возможности.

Что думаете?

Answer (score 3):

Я не вижу причин для закрытия подобных вопросов. Другое дело, что ответ на них будет субъективным, что может понравиться не всем участникам. Хотя моё мнение,  небольшое количество спорных вопрос лишь повысит интерес к форуму, благо появились модераторы.

Правда, задавая подобные вопросы нужно понимать, что большинство участников сообщества далеки от программирования и электронного дизайна и объяснять все подробно.

Comment: Ответ на такие вопросы будет гораздо более объективен, чем на вопросы по метке [tag:этимология], где половина ответов даётся лингвофриками.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что подобные вопросы лучше "вынести за скобки" обсуждения на основном форуме. 
1. Ответ заведомо субъективен, ибо авторитетных рекомендаций по ним нет. А что такое обсуждения субъективных вопросов при данном составе участников, мы уже проходили.
2. Тематика сама по себе далека от сложившейся. Да, можно спорить, являются эти вопросы оффтиком "вообще", но у нас-то границы определяются не общими рассуждениями, а представлениями сообщества о возможности и целесообразности поиска ответа на в конкретной ситуации. Так что можно считать, что оффтопик. Впрочем, я давно предлагал взять за основу какой-то курс и посмотреть, какая тематика там затрагивается, от этого и танцевать. Не встретил понимания.
3. *Нельзя объять необъятного* (Козьма Прутков). Даже если мы пойдем по пути бесконечного расширения тематики, границы все равно придется обозначить. Так что в очередной предлагаю все-таки не запрягать телегу впереди лошади, определить раз и навсегда ***критерий***, по которому считать тему оффтопной, а не заниматься этим каждый раз, когда кому-то захотелось расширить список вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

[Вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429747/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8) не выходит за рамки тематики сайта: в нем спрашивается о пунктуационных нормах. Хотя действительно классификация всплывающих подсказок может вызвать затруднения: что это — своеобразный вид заглавия или же самостоятельное предложение?

Правила сообщества устанавливаются самим сообществом, поэтому внести предложение может каждый участник, однако желательно создать отдельный вопрос с метками [предложение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [справка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Вопросы по верстке не запрещены правилами, так что, в общем-то, как мне кажется, ничего плохого в них нет.

Comment: Верстка per se - оффтопик. Есть Webmasters - пусть там и тусят, не одним сеошникам там сохнуть

Answer (score -1):

Надо заметить, что абсурдно теоретически рассматривать вопросы дизайна, они могут обсуждаться только на уровне картинки, вариантов формы, цвета, движения. (Сайт готов к этому?) Главное же то, что это — заведомо субъективная сфера со своими писанными и неписанными законами, связанная с диктатом и вкусами заказывающего музыку. Консультировать (вмешиваться в процесс никто не должен) на серьёзном, доказательном уровне  исполнителя-дизайнера или критиковать его — в нашей «аудитории» дело неблагодарное.

На то есть имеющие вес компании, глобально занимающиеся графическим дизайном, изданием книг,строительством сайтов. Их много, некоторые дают советы даром.

Однако, если вопрос по этой тематике будет носить не профессиональный характер, а на уровне интереса к детали дизайнерского решения, его, наверное, не хорошо оставлять без внимания.

Comment: Вопрос не имел отношения к графическому дизайну. Речь в нём шла об использовании русского языка в интерфейсе сайта.

Comment: Интерфейс и есть продукт дизайна. Решение в любой его области (разговор был о меню, а не об использовании русского языка в интерфейсе сайта), слаженная работа деталей интерфейса — ответственность графического дизайна. Даже если «Пунктуация — это не инструмент вёрстки», любой знак может быть отброшен дизайнером или заменён хоть на зеркальный (была бы идея, смысл, вкус). А со вкусами не спорят.

Comment: Вы считаете, что вопрос касается дизайна или строительства сайтов? Спросил мнение профессионального дизайнера — это важно в работе дизайнера, но это не дизайн. Собственно к сайтостроению тоже точно не относится, там чисто технологические вопросы. О «слаженной работе деталей интерфейса» тоже речи не шло.

Comment: А вы можете привести пример, когда дизайнер может взять и отбросить знак препинания или заменить его? Кстати, что такое «зеркальный знак препинания»? Мне такая вольность с трудом представляется возможной.

Comment: Знак вопроса и восклицательный вниз головой встречаются чаще, чем хотелось бы. Нижнее подчёркивание используется в отсутствие знака на строке.

Answer (score -1):

Вопросы об использовании русского языка в интерфейсе сайта — подмножество вопросов об использовании русского языка вообще. Очевидно, что **такие вопросы входят в тематику сайта**.

Про это:

> [Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что относится к вёрстке электронных текстов.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35052283#35052283)

[Вёрстка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) — это графическое оформление текста. Она затрагивает шрифты, отступы, выравнивание, начертание, таблицы, расстояния между символами и строками и прочее подобное. Пунктуация — это не инструмент вёрстки.

То, что текст электронный — нормальная ситуация. Большинство текстов, которые мы видим сегодня — либо электронные, либо хотя бы прошли электронную обработку. На сайтах и в приложениях широко используется специфическая форма письменной речи: короткие подписи, подсказки, названия кнопок и элементов меню. *Если правил русского языка для сайтов и программ ещё нет, их необходимо выработать.*