# Тотальный диктант и rusSE

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-проверка

В продолжение топика [Развитие сообщества «Русский язык»](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA/167#167).

Как вы знаете, на днях будет проходить ежегодный "Тотальный диктант" ([википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), [офсайт](https://totaldict.ru/)).

И нам и им интересно расширение аудитории. Наверняка не все участники сообщества знают о этом мероприятии и наоборот -- далеко не все пишущие в курсе того, где можно задать вопрос по тематике русского языка и получить ответ.

Будет ли интересно ли нам такое сотрудничество? Не знаю, насколько более качественные вопросы мы получим, гарантированно может возрасти только количество вопросов. Но мне кажется, что это привлечёт не только задающих вопросы, но и отвечающих на вопросы.

Comment: Я передал ваше обращение администрации сайта. Пожалуйста, ожидайте ответа.

Comment: Написал организатором мероприятия. Как мне кажется, мы бы легко смогли стать их информационным партнером (так как на нашем сайте нет коммерческой рекламы, вполне вероятно было бы разместить их баннеры). С другой стороны, до мероприятия осталось буквально несколько дней. Не уверен, что получится организовать что–либо в столь сжаты сроки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мероприятие ежегодное.

Comment: @AK Ага, понял. В любом случае, жду ответа от организаторов! Как только что–либо станет известно, сразу отпишусь!